# Using OpenStack API to access SoftLayer resources

Tags: openstack, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, rackspace

I'm trying to use OpenStack API to access SoftLayer resources.

So far I had been trying to use Jumpgate without success.

Do you know if is it possible to access SoftLayer resources using OpenStack API, not only Object Storage ?

In case that it is not possible, do you know if Rackspace does support OpenStack API ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is not possible to access SoftLayer resources through OpenStack API. You can only access to Object Storage, because it is based on OpenStack Swift.

Regarding to Rackspace, I think is the same idea, they should have his own API to access its resources.

Answer (score 0):

I can say with absolute certainty that you can use the OpenStack API with Rackspace. For docs and tools see https://developer.rackspace.com/